# How to automatically use SKYPE when calling international number?

Tags: tasker, skype, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I'd like to program my phone such that if I call an international number it'd automatically use skype (or ask me to connect to skype if not connected), and if I call within the US it'd just use my phone.

Examples:

+1 -> always use my phone

+56 (or other international codes) -> always use Skype.

Any suggestions?  I think tasker could help but I am new to tasker so I am still looking on how to program this kind of flows in tasker... I am open to other software/ideas as well.  Maybe it could be even more general, instead of using skype it could use any other VoIP good service (I am mostly familiar with Skype but I am sure there are other great services).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have to check that as well, as I never tried such. A good ressource on this is the [Tasker UserGuide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/). Hm, strange: all phone-related events seem to be about incoming calls only. So this might need another plugin -- and here comes the second ressource: [mine](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/435917/). Hm, but it looks like there are only plugins for incoming calls, or SIP, or GoogleVoice. Wait: Maybe [Call Monitor Locale Plug-in](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brilliantintent.plugins.locale.conditions.callmonitor)?

Comment: Great Question... It can really be useful to all calling international number..

Comment: @Izzy, thanks a lot! i am still trying to figure it out but I think we are in the right direction

Comment: Keep us updated, please, once you've got that working. You know, you can answer your own question :)

Answer (score 1):

On Android => 2.3 there is an option in phone settings under `Internet Call Settings` to add VOIP accounts as well as option `Use Internet calling` with the following options:

- For all calls when data network is available
- Only for Internet calls
- Ask for each call

Using the third option is the closest you can get currently to your required way of doing this, using a regular SIP instead of Skype.

*Note: Some devices might not have these options even though they are later versions.

Answer (score 1):

With a launcher such as Nova Launcher, you could use a custom activity launcher and use the activity witch is the dial pad of skype. That will allow you to launch the right dial pad when calling a foreign number.

Answer (score 0):

Tasker cannot help. Neither can android. Because android cannot differentiate between international and local numbers. You can however make your own app if you can code ;)